# Redirect to url based on current year/month

Tags: templating, redirect

I've got a calendar template set up and would like to have http://domain.com/calendar redirect to http://domain.com/calendar/current_year/current_month but am having trouble getting this to work.

My current code is:

```
{% if craft.request.segment(2) == "" %}
  {% redirect "calendar/{{ now.year }}/{{ now.month }}" %}
{% endif %}
```

But this ends up going to a 404 with this url:
http://domain.com/calendar/%7B%7B%20now.year%20%7D%7D/%7B%20now.month%20%7D/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never use `{{` echo tags within other Twig tags. What you have to do instead is to use string concatenation.
`{% redirect "calendar/" ~ now.year ~ "/" ~ now.month %}`

Comment: That works but it's outputting "8" for august rather than "08" how would I get the leading zero?

Comment: found it:  ~ now|date("m")